# Android `JavascriptInterface` object exists, But It doesn't have any method intermittently

Tags: android, webview

I have tried to leverage web in my Android service using `JavascriptInterface`. Mostly it works well, but intermittently  `interface cannot find` error occurs.

What I found out by debugging is that:

1. When the error occurred, `JavascriptInterface` Object exists. When I logged the Object, the reference of the object was logged well. That means object itself is successfully injected from native.

```js
console.log(window['javascriptinterface']) // [object Object]
```

2. When the error occurred, there's no method on `JavascriptInterface` object which was well defined in native code.

```js
console.log(window['javascriptinterface']?.someMethod) // undefined
```

I have stewed over this problem long time, but I failed to find any explicit clue.
Currently I suspect that there might be some issue when to invoke `javascriptinterface` too early. Is it possible for web to invoke `javascriptinterface` before `javascriptinterface` object initiate?

Is there anyone who experienced this issue?

Comment: Did you called your `webview.addJavascriptInterface(obj, interfaceName)`?

Comment: Of course ;) so the interface object itself existed without any methods @fobidlim